# Proof of "generic curve of genus at least 2 has no nontrivial maps to a positive genus curve"

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces

I searched for it for a long time, but it seems that everybody is taking this for granted and does not bother to point out a proof. Would it be possible that someone points me to a proof or makes me see the obvious.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is your definition of "generic"?  I expect that there are countably many subvarieties in the moduli space parameterizing curves that admit a positive degree morphism to some genus 1 curve.

Comment: Of course, Jason is correct. However,  a *very general* point of $M_g$ (by which I mean, exclude a countable union of proper sub varieties) corresponds to a curve with a simple Jacobian. This curve can't map onto  anything of smaller genus. (This is over $\mathbb{C}$.)

Comment: @DonuArapura Could you give me a reference published somewhere? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DonuArapura because the set of morphism is a map between this union of sub varieties to $\cup M_{g_i<g}$ ? Is this the classical proof?

Comment: For your first question, it follows from from Cor.  17.5.2 of Birkenhake and Lange's book on Complex Abelian Varieties (2nd ed), but I'm sure there are more suitable references.

Comment: @DonuArapura, Thanks a lot, if you write it as an answer, I'll be able to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, here's an answer. As I said in the comments, if the $C$ is a (smooth  projective) curve with a simple Jacobian, then it can't map onto a curve of smaller genus. Since I was a bit curious myself, 
I found a reference for the next step: Koizumi "The ring of correspondences on a generic curve of genus g" Nagoya (1976).
The result is better than I expected! Koizumi proves that if $C$ is the geometric generic curve of $M_g$ over the algebraic closure of the prime field, then $End(J( C) =\mathbb{Z}$; so in particular, it is simple.